# SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE GCM android

Tags: android, eclipse, google-cloud-messaging

I've been developing an android application with no problem until now. Everything worked fine last week but today I tryed to register to the GCM server and I'm getting a Service_not_available.
I've searched all over the web as to what can be the cause of this because it worked last week, still no solution found. I'm using the example from the GCM Server in the android developers.
This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<permission
    android:name="com.testing.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.testing.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icono_aplicacion"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:name="com.testing.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:name="com.testing.Inicio"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.testing.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="com.testing" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.testing" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.testing.GCMIntentService" />
```

and the application throws an exception when I call.

```
 String regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
```

Any ideas how to fix this? I've already tryed on 4 devices with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html#ERROR_SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE) might mean that your device can't read the response or there was a 500/503 from the server. You can try and have a exponential back-off and retry again. You already have `"com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"` , so I assume you are handling the refreshing of ID's in the `BroadCastReceiver`. Also check if you are logged in to Google from your device. You ofcourse need a valid Google account for using the service. If you have changed password, just check if logged in. There is also a similar [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&q=57699&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&id=57699#makechanges) which is still unresolved. Keep track of it.

That's my 2 cents for you problem.

Comment: Turns out you were right. As adding a Broadcast receiver I was able to get the regID. Sometimes gcm.register() works and sometimes it doesn't, but the broadcastreceiver always get the code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance setting a breakpoint prior to calling gcm.register()? This will cause issues because the device time will become out of sync with the gcm servers and cause the call to fail.

Comment: No, in fact, now I'm trying to capture the registration ID from the BroadcastReceiver and it looks like its working so maybe as Shobhit Puri said it's a bug